# Calculate press tonnage from impact momentum

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have an application where a person drives a bush into its housing using a hammer of about 3kgs.
Suppose the same application is to be done with a hydraulic press,is it possible to calculate the press tonnage(probably using an approximated calculation of the kinetic energy of the hammer).
TIA
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your hammer strike, moving at a speed of 4 meters/s, drives the bushing into its housing by 1 centimeter .

Therefore the kinetic energy of hammer $ K_e=\frac{1}{2}m*v^2 $ has Been used to move the bushing. Annotating "d" as the distance the bushing travels and ignoring its weight.

$$ F_{average}d=- \frac{1}{2}m*v^2 \\ F_{average}= \frac{ \frac{1}{2}m*v^2}{d} $$

$$F_{press}= \frac{\frac{1}{2}3kg*4^2}{1cm}*\frac{100cm}{1meter}=2400kg $$